# What is wrong with my Qt environment? It reports "could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""."

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plugins, qt

Five months ago I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04.  Following this upgrade several Qt applications no longer worked for me.  Instead of starting up I would see errors such as:

```
$ git cola &
[1] 9534
$ This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
error: git-cola died of signal 6
^C
[1]+ Exit 134 git cola
```

(I considered asking this on Ask Ubuntu as that is my operating system but it could be a wider Qt environment on Linux issue so I shall start here.  This is not git-cola specific, as I see a very similar message on other applications.)

Several posts on the www suggested that a related package might be missing but so far I have not been able to identify what.  Running with `export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` set gives more debug information but no answers as far as I can work out:

```
$ export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1
$ git-cola
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/bin/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 329989
}


...<trimming out the rest of the OK stuff until we reach>...


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZNK15QPlatformWindow15safeAreaMarginsEv version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference)
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: symbol _ZNK15QPlatformWindow15safeAreaMarginsEv version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference)"
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I run the application with `ldd` or check the package which should be providing *xcb* all seems to be present and correct.

```
$ env LANG=C ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc489e3000)
    libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007fd3090c8000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007fd308919000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007fd3081de000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fd307e50000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd307a5f000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd307749000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007fd307504000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007fd307250000)
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007fd306fc6000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd306da7000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007fd306ba5000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007fd30686c000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fd30665c000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fd306454000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fd306239000)
    libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007fd30601d000)
    libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0x00007fd305e19000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007fd305c0c000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007fd305a05000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007fd3057fd000)
    libxcb-xinerama.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-xinerama.so.0 (0x00007fd3055fa000)
    libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007fd3053ea000)
    libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007fd3051e5000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007fd304fe2000)
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007fd304ddf000)
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007fd304bda000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007fd3049b2000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007fd3047ae000)
    libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 (0x00007fd3045a6000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007fd304367000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd303fc9000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fd303db1000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fd303b25000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fd303908000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007fd30346f000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007fd3030b7000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007fd3016d4000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd3014d0000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007fd3012ce000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd3095ce000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fd30105c000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fd300e2a000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007fd300bf8000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007fd3009ab000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007fd300799000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007fd300592000)
    libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007fd30037d000)
    libxcb-util.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.1 (0x00007fd300177000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007fd2fff73000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007fd2ffd6d000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007fd2ffb3c000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007fd2ff886000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007fd2ff602000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fd2ff3fa000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fd2ff1d4000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007fd2fefb8000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fd2fec9d000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fd2fea88000)
```

Several of the applcations I have issues with offer a seperate container or packaging solution such as *snap* or *flatpak*.  While this provides me with a workaround in many cases, I would still like to be able to resolve the issue with my Qt environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a Qt libraries version mismatch.

I see Qt libraries coming from both `/usr/bin/platforms/libqeglfs.so` and
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms`, which are probably not consistent.

You might need to specify the path like this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/right/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Your suggested workaround has got everything to work correctly!  Now I just need to find why I am in the wrong state.

Comment: Interestingly the two directories pointed to would be consistent: `/usr/bin/platforms -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/` I am not sure that symlink is needed though.

Comment: @harrymc, should that be "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/right/libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" instead (= character instead of :)? If so, can you fix this? I tried editing your reply, but it insists on more character changes to accept the edit...

Comment: @frog.ca: You're absolutely right - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Now experienced similar problem for TeamViewer 15.  After some extra installs of multimedia packages as well as of MATLAB get problems with TeamViewer client not starting.

Sometimes get this in /var/log/messages:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.

This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.#012#012

Available platform plugins are: xcb.
```

Always attempts writing this to this system log when doing strace!

If running

```
QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 strace teamviewer
```

you could see TeamViewer attempting to report this in logs.  Same printout as the one in messages also occurs in `~/.local/share/teamviewer15/logfiles/gui.log`, but it is not persistent when experimenting with this.

Actual problem is that `/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/RTlib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so` has an unfulfilled requirement when dynamically loaded.  Checking by command

```
ldd /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/RTlib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
```

you get

```
/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/RTlib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: /usr/lib64/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: version `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/RTlib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so) /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/RTlib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: /usr/lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/RTlib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so) 
...
```

Dynamic loading of requirements as by ldd is governed by environment variable setting in .bashrc

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64
```

---

Problem solved itself after removing environment variable
setting of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `.bashrc` so that dynamic loading and
ldd does not find that library when running TeamViewer!